# goroutine hangs when passing data

Tags: go, concurrency

given the following variables

```
wg.Add(4)
pDayResCh := make(chan map[string]map[string]int)
pDayErrCh := make(chan error)
```

The following code hangs

```golang
    // Convert the previous, current, and next day prayers and put them in map
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("executing first go routine") // TODO: Remove this line after debug
        data, err := dayPrayerMapConv(previousDayPrayers)
        fmt.Printf("first goroutine result %v\n", data) // TODO: Remove this line after debug
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("first goroutine err != nil %v\n", err)
            pDayErrCh <- err
        }
        fmt.Printf("first goroutine putting data into channel")
        pDayResCh <- data
        fmt.Printf("first go routine finished") // TODO: Remove this line after debug
        wg.Done()
    }()

    pDayErr := <-pDayErrCh
    close(pDayErrCh)
    if pDayErr != nil {
        return pDayErr
    }

    fmt.Println("pday err finised")
    p.PreviousDayPrayers = <-pDayResCh
    close(pDayResCh)
```

This is the result of the print statement

```
first goroutine result map[Asr:map[Hour:3 Minute:28] Dhuhr:map[Hour:12 Minute:23] Fajr:map[Hour:5 Minute:32] Isha:map[Hour:7 Minute:5] Maghrib:map[Hour:6 Minute:13]]
first goroutine putting data into channel
```

So there is data in the `data` variable that should have been passed into pDayResCh, but it seems to get stuck there, why?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the condition in my goroutine where I check for the error

```
if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("first goroutine err != nil %v\n", err)
            pDayErrCh <- err
        }
```

Because error is nil, that data never gets passed into the channel, thus hangs

Removing the condition and passing the err regardless solves the issue.